# Ethers ContractFactory not working for polygon mainnet

Tags: polygon, alchemy

I'm using ethers' ContractFactory to deploy a contract with Alchemy RPCs.

```
async deployContract(contractObject: ContractObjectDto) {
    try {
      const chain = contractObject.chain.toLowerCase() as Chains;
      const network = contractObject.network.toLowerCase() as Networks;

      const Factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(
        this.getContractInterface(contractObject.type).abi,
        this.getContractInterface(contractObject.type).bytecode,
        this.getSigner(chain, network),
      );

      const contract = await Factory.deploy(
          contractObject.name,
          contractObject.symbol,
      );

      await contract.deployed();

      return contract.address;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

It works for Arbitrum Mainnet/Goerli, Optimism Mainnet/Goerli, and Polygon Mumbai. However, it fails for Polygon Mainnet. There, I get the error:

```
Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":47,\"error\":
{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"transaction underpriced\"}}", 
error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":...
```

Even if I specify the gas, like below, I still get the error. I have also tried using an Infura RPC, but the result is the same.

```
const provider = getWeb3ProviderThroughEthers(chain, network);

const price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(
   await provider.getGasPrice(),
   'gwei',
);

contract = await Factory.deploy(
  contractObject.name,
  contractObject.symbol,
  {
    gasLimit: 100000,
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, 'gwei'),
  },
);
```

Comment: Did you check if there's a pending transaction?

Comment: Take a look on Curvegrid blog post. Maybe your issue is related with: https://www.curvegrid.com/blog/2022-11-21-polygon-transaction-underpriced